# MariaDB query issue | query works when index is specified or ignored but fails to return expected results otherwise| Why would this occur?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, rdbms

I'm trying to get results of a query from schools that were in a particular region over time. I've created the queries that I think should do this -

```
SELECT *
FROM team t1
JOIN district_team t2 ON t1.school_name = t2.team_name
join district t3 ON t2.district_num = t3.districut_number
JOIN region_district t4 ON (t2.season = t4.season AND t3.districut_number = t4.district_num AND t4.region_num = 3);

SELECT result.school_name, result.region_num, result.season
FROM (SELECT * from team t1
JOIN district_team t2 ON t1.school_name = t2.team_name
join district t3 ON t2.district_num = t3.districut_number
NATURAL JOIN region_district t4)result
WHERE result.region_num = 3;
```

but these queries give no results even though the first query gives results that are in region 3.

[image: queries that should do almost the same thing - return results that are from region 3]

--- Schema of tables in query ---

```
CREATE TABLE `team` (
    `school_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `mascot_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`school_name`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
CREATE TABLE `district_team` (
    `district_num` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `team_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `season` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `district_fk` (`district_num`),
    INDEX `team_district_fk` (`team_name`),
    CONSTRAINT `district_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`district_num`) REFERENCES `district` (`districut_number`),
    CONSTRAINT `team_district_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`team_name`) REFERENCES `team` (`school_name`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
CREATE TABLE `district` (
    `districut_number` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`districut_number`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
CREATE TABLE `region_district` (
    `district_num` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `region_num` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `season` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX `region_fk` (`region_num`),
    INDEX `district_region_fk` (`district_num`),
    CONSTRAINT `district_region_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`district_num`) REFERENCES `district` (`districut_number`),
    CONSTRAINT `region_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`region_num`) REFERENCES `region` (`region_number`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Does anyone know why this would be the case or what's going on here? Could this be a character encoding issue?

UPDATE---

The Query works when I tell the table which index to use or to ignore the index.
So these queries give the expected output --

```
SELECT *
FROM team t1
JOIN district_team t2 ON t1.school_name = t2.team_name
join district t3 ON t2.district_num = t3.districut_number
JOIN region_district t4 IGNORE INDEX(region_fk) ON (t2.season = t4.season AND t3.districut_number = t4.district_num AND t4.region_num = 3);

SELECT *
FROM team t1
JOIN district_team t2 ON t1.school_name = t2.team_name
join district t3 ON t2.district_num = t3.districut_number
JOIN region_district t4 use INDEX(region_fk) ON (t2.season = t4.season AND t3.districut_number = t4.district_num AND t4.region_num = 3);
```

But this query doesn't

```
SELECT *
FROM team t1
JOIN district_team t2 ON t1.school_name = t2.team_name
join district t3 ON t2.district_num = t3.districut_number
JOIN region_district t4 ON (t2.season = t4.season AND t3.districut_number = t4.district_num AND t4.region_num = 3);
```

Does anyone know why this would occur?

[image of above query execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4m2U.png)

Comment: `t1.school_name = t2.team_name`? Are you looking for teams the names of which equal school names?

Comment: Hey @ThorstenKettner thanks for the help!! The overall database is to store high school sports data. School_name and team_name would have almost the same meaning in this context. t1 is the team table and it joins to t2 which is a bridge table to district. Every year a team will belong to a district and each year that district will belong to a region and I wanted to store the history of that as well as some details about the district and region if necessary. Let me know if that clears things up for you!

Comment: Seems like there may be a problem with the index, try repairing it.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in sqlfiddle?

Comment: Hey @Barmar, Thanks for the help! I recreated the schema and inserted a subset of the data in sqlfiddle and I'm not having the issue there. The query is working as expected there [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7847a1/2). I will try to see if there is an issue with my index.

Comment: You could also try https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4 in case the problem is specific to MariaDB.

Comment: I got the same working with mariadb on dbfiddle [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1d6a6d9bce36bdc01c30af088f3dd630](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1d6a6d9bce36bdc01c30af088f3dd630). I only had to make the table name match cases in ddl / dml as it seemed to be running with a *nix back-end. I will try the same locally and see if that resolves the issue. I'll also try to recreate the schema and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Use `ON` for saying how tables relate; use `WHERE` for filtering.  (You are _filtering_ on `region_num`.)

Comment: Hey @RickJames, I wrote a query with the same goal using where instead of filtering in the join. See lines 13-18 on the first screenshot for this query. For some reason it still returned no results unless I specify which index to use or ignore the index. Both of those approaches produce expected output. Is it bad practice to filter on joins like I've done? If so why? Thanks!

Comment: @CoreyRobinson - For `LEFT JOIN`, the placement of conditions changes the output; no change for regular `JOIN`.  My Comment is "best practice" in that it helps readers better understand what is going on.  (I am baffled as to what is causing your problem.)